# Eclipse toolbar middle alignment (GTK related)

Tags: eclipse, centos, ide, gtk, toolbar

Installed fresh installation of Eclipse on centos.
After restarting suddenly all buttons are aligned middle instead of left.
Where is the setting to change that?
[image]

Eclipse version 4.16.0
Build id 20200615-1200

Edit: seem to be a GTK problem, I managed to find those settings in gtk inspector using ctrl+shift+D and change the toolbar elements to GTK_ALIGN_START, and that fixes it.
But no idea why it's like that to begin with? All my other apps works, and all use GTK_ALIGN_FILL, only eclipse is like that.
Also new eclipse installation doesn't help.

Any way to change all gtk aligns for a program and save?

Comment: Eclipse uses native menus. How are the menus displayed in other applications? Do you get the same with the current Eclipse version instead of the outdated one you have? Which GTK version do you have?

Comment: All works in all other apps, it's only eclipse like that. I didn't install the new eclipse because we don't have the latest Java in our company. I'll try figuring out which gtk I use.

Comment: Also I found that opening the gtk inspector I could manually change halign of the buttons to GTK_ALIGN_START, and that would fix it. But no idea how to apply it to all and make permanent. But it does seem like GTK issue.

Comment: Also gtk in use is 3.14.13